# Show day total count using jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daycount

I am using [jQuery ui datepicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and applied a date format like this

> Wednesday, 30 April, 2016

Here is the code

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="closedate">
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#closedate").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy' });
});
```

Now how can I add day count from current date like this in my input?

> Wednesday, 30 April, 2016 (3 Days)

[image: demo]

3 days in bracket is a *count from current date*

Comment: @ArunPJohny, It is _count from current date_

Comment: @Arun P Johny the day count from current date, today is 27 and I have selected 30 so 30-27=3

Comment: @Rayon Dabre Right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just addition over [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36566839/1746830) provided by [*DDan*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3278822/ddan)

Use `onSelect` event and you can use `formatted` value framed by provided formatter.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#closedate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy',
    onSelect: function(a, b) {
      var diff = new Date() - $(this).datepicker("getDate");
      diff = Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) * -1) + 1;
      var value = a + '(' + diff + ' days)'
      $(this).val(value);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="closedate" size='50'>
```

### [**Fiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8w8v9/1293/)

Answer (score 3):

You count calculate on change event of datepicker input.

See example Code:

```
$('#date1').change(function() {
    var diff = new Date() - $('#date1').datepicker("getDate");
    $('#diff').text(Math.floor(diff / (1000*60*60*24) * -1) + 1);
});
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jvxz6g4c/

**EDIT**

Edited version after your comment:

Added some extra string formatting and date utils:

```
$('#date1').change(function() {
    var pickedDate = $('#date1').datepicker("getDate");
    var diff = new Date() - $('#date1').datepicker("getDate");
    var dayDiff = Math.floor(diff / (1000*60*60*24) * -1) + 1;

    $('#pickedDate').text(getDatStr(pickedDate));
    $('#diff').text('(' + dayDiff + ' Days )');
});

var monthNames = [
  "January", "February", "March",
  "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October",
  "November", "December"
];

var days = ['Sunday','Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday'];

function getDatStr(date) {
  var day = date.getDate();
  var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
  var year = date.getFullYear();
  var dayOfWeek = date.getDay();

  return days[dayOfWeek] + ', ' + day + ' ' + monthNames[monthIndex] + ', ' +  year;
}
```

See it working:

https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jvxz6g4c/2/

**EDIT**

Small edits based on comment

https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jvxz6g4c/4/

Slightly closer: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/jvxz6g4c/6

Comment: this is great!! But I have date in this `Wednesday, 30 April, 2016 (n Days)` in this format

Comment: Edited based on your example. I hope it helps.

Comment: hey can you look at the image I have attached, so you can better understand, You have did great job but i want to print that value inside input

Comment: Sure thing! See edited. You can add some nice styling to it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help, see version 5, it's a bit closer to what you planned to get.

Comment: Nice effort BUT look at my clean and compressed code

Answer (score 1):

This may help: [Get difference between 2 dates in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3224834/get-difference-between-2-dates-in-javascript)

Essentially convert the value returned from the datepicker in to a standard JS date.

```
var date1 = new Date("7/13/2010");
var date2 = new Date("12/15/2010");
var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 
alert(diffDays);
```

Comment: I dont want to use two dates and datepicker, I want to use only one date picker and first date will be current date and other date will be selected date

Answer (score 1):

**CODE:** https://jsfiddle.net/5pr7uhc0/

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="date">Date:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
        <input id="date1" value="Pick Date" type="button" class="form-control btn btn-default" name="training_start_date" value=""> 
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<span id="pickedDate">  </span>  <span id='diff'>  </span>
```

Jquery:

```
$('#date1').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'DD, d MM, yy' });

$('#date1').change(function() {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    var today = new Date();
    var dayDiff = Math.ceil((today - date) / (1000*60*60*24) * -1);
    $('#date1').val($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d MM, yy', date) + ' ( ' + dayDiff + ' Days )');
});
```

Just cleaned code from @DDan.